# Get maximum value of nested class property - Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have a class that has the following format:

```
  class Student(var name: String) {
   var name: String? = null
   var Math: Course? = null
   var English: Course? = null
   var Spanish: Course? = null

  
   }

  class Course {
    var id: Int
    var courseGrade: Int? = null
   }
```

And I have a variable that is of type Student

```
    var studentData = Student("test")
```

I need to iterate through all courses and get the grade of the highest course that's in class Student, to assign it to a "highestScore" variable.
How can I iterate through the properties that have values in other class types?

Comment: The code you provided is not valid Kotlin. Could you please update your class definitions with the actual code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Student` class is not designed properly for such a feature (you would need reflection to do what you want, which is really not advised here).

If you need to consider courses as a collection of things (to be able to iterate on them or perform operations on them), you should represent it as such in your class. For instance, you can use `List<Course>`:

```kotlin
class Student(
    val name: String? = null,
    val courses: List<Course> = emptyList(),
)

class Course(
    val id: Int,
    val name: String,
    val courseGrade: Int? = null
)
```

Then you can easily get the information you need:

```kotlin
val maxGrade = studentData.courses
                          .filter { it.courseGrade != null }
                          .maxOfOrNull { it.courseGrade!! }
```

But probably it would be better to not have a nullable grade here. Is it expected to have some course instances without a grade? If not, making it non-nullable makes the code even simpler:

```kotlin
val maxGrade = studentData.courses.maxOfOrNull { it.courseGrade }
```

---

If you ***really have to*** stick with this class structure, then I see mainly 2 solutions to get the list of courses (and then apply the above):

1. list properties by hand
2. find properties via reflection

For #1:

```kotlin
val courses = listOfNotNull(student.Math, student.English, student.Spanish)
```

Or to make it less verbose if you have many courses properties:

```kotlin
val courses = with(student) { listOfNotNull(Math, English, Spanish) }
```

For #2 (requires `kotlin-reflect` and honestly I really don't advise this):

```kotlin
private fun KProperty1<Student, *>.isNullableCourseType() = returnType.isSubtypeOf(Course::class.createType(nullable = true))
```

And then:

```kotlin
val courses = Student::class.memberProperties
                            .filter { it.isNullableCourseType() }
                            .mapNotNull { it.get(studentData) }
```

Comment: Thank you, and I agree that would make more sense and is better practice, but I am not allowed to change the format and the classes. This is how the data is already processed and provided, I just need to find the maximum grade to display :\

Comment: @JamesJ is this an assignment? If yes, then I wonder what the learning goal is for this. The solutions I see are either listing all properties by hand, or using reflection - and I don't believe either is good practice. If this is not an assignment, then I believe you should change the Student class. If this comes from JSON deserialization, you could create a custom deserializer to populate a list.

Comment: It was an internship project for which all the processing data had already been done, but needed to add the highest grade, s o I had to stick by the structure. I have just started learning Kotlin. Thank you for all the details and suggestions on best practices! Truuuuly appreciate it!!